# Alumni or alumnus?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Can I say "An alumni of x university recommended this course to me", if there is only one person who recommended me the course?

Comment: Alumnus is singular.  Alumni is plural.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can and people do, but they're mistaken.

The singular is *alumnus* for men and *alumna* for women. The plural is *alumni* for men or mixed groups and *alumnae* for women. It's from Latin and common enough that *alumnuses* is going to get you a side eye but you run the risk of coming across as undereducated if you use the plural form for a single person.

That said, it's a minor bit of grammar in a non-English language and it's not going to cause any major problems unless the prof already dislikes you.